# Closed-form solution for this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, recursion

We have a differential equation
$$\frac{d\phi_\nu(t)}{dt}-\xi(\omega+\phi_{\nu-1}(t)-\phi_{\nu}(t))=0$$
When time is up, we have $\phi_\nu(0)=0$ for all values of $\nu \ge 1$, which is an integer environmental factor and also $\phi_0(t)=0$ at all times.

If we start from $\nu=1$ and recursively solve the equation for some values of $\nu$, we get
$$\phi_\nu(t)=\omega\nu-\sum_{i=0}^{\nu-1}\frac{i+1}{(\nu-i-1)!}(\xi t)^{\nu-i-1}\omega e^{-\xi t}$$

But I only solved the equation for $\nu=1,\ldots,5$, and this formulation is true for those values.  How can I prove this is the general form of $\phi$?

Comment: How did you solve it for $\nu=1$ ? One needs an initial term $\phi_0(t)$. In general, you should plug your ansatz into the original equation to check its validity.

Comment: Boundary conditions?

Comment: @Abezhiko Thank you for pointing this out. $\phi_0(t) = 0$. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Constructing a solution from the first successive steps may be quite uncertain. Here is a more systematic method to deal with this equation.

Laplace transform allows you to "sweep the derivative under the carpet" in order to focus on the recurrence relation. Defining
$$
\Phi_\nu(s) = \int_{0^-}^\infty \phi_\nu(t)e^{-st} \mathrm{d}t,
$$
the original differential equation becomes
$$
s\Phi_\nu(s) -\xi\left(\frac{\omega}{s} + \Phi_{\nu-1}(s) - \Phi_\nu(s)\right) = 0,
$$
hence the following recurrence relation :
$$
\Phi_\nu(s) = \frac{\Phi_{\nu-1}(s)}{s+\xi^{-1}} + \frac{\omega}{s(s+\xi^{-1})}
$$
This nonhomogeneous first-order linear recurrence relation (with constant coefficients with respect to $\nu$) leads easily to
$$
\Phi_\nu(s) = \frac{\Phi_0(s)}{(s+\xi^{-1})^\nu} + \frac{\omega}{s^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{(s+\xi^{-1})^\nu}\right)
$$
Then you still need to take the inverse Laplace transform, but the result will depend on the initial term $\Phi_0(s)$ (that you didn't specify).

Comment: Inverse transform: $\phi_v(t) = \int_0^t \phi_0(t-t') \frac{t'^{1-\nu}e^{-t'/\xi}}{\Gamma(\nu)} dt' + \omega \int_0^t  (t-t')\Big(\delta(t') - \frac{t'^{1-\nu}e^{-t'/\xi}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\Big)dt'$, which is similar to OP's suggested solution.